# Finding the tangent line to a curve at a given point?

Tags: calculus

Find the equation for the tangent line to curve at the point $x = 4/\pi:$

$$y= x^2\sec(1/x).$$

This is what I have so far:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= 2x\sec(1/x)-\sec(1/x)\tan(1/x)x^2.$$

How can I complete this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have $-sec(1/x)tan(1/x)x^2$. Where did the negative sign come from? Product rule is +.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ gives you the slope of the tangent line at any point. Substituting in a value for $x$ into $\frac{dy}{dx}$ gives you the slope at that particular value. Now you have the slope of the line, how do you get the equation of the line?

Answer (score 0):

From high school algebra, you know that to get the equation of a line you need two things:  A point on the line and the slope.  You're given the $x$-coordinate of a point on the line (and the curve.)  So find the $y$-coordinate.  Now you need the slope at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to solve such a problem:

1. Differentiate your function $f(x)$ (as you have done) and insert the value of $x=x_t$ which represents the point you want to find the tangent line at, i.e., $f'(x_t)$.
2. You want to find an equation of the form $g(x)=ax+b$, where you already know $a$. To find $b$, simply insert the point you know $g(x)$ must satisfy, i.e., $g(x_t)=f(x_t)$.

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the tangent line is
$$
y'(4/\pi)=2(4/\pi)\sec(\pi/4)-\sec(\pi/4)\tan(\pi/4)=\frac{16}{\sqrt{2}\pi}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
And the line must go through the point $(\frac{4}{\pi},\frac{16}{\pi^2}*\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}})$
Can you finish from here?

Comment: To finish it just put it in the form $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$

Comment: So would it be y- 16/pi^2 * 2/sqrt2 = (16/sqrt2pi - 2/sqrt2) * (x-4/pi)?

Comment: Assuming I didn't make any mistakes computing, yes